# How do can I make my car sprite move. I have three separate python files

Tags: python, pygame

I want to keep my moving function in my car.py file because I have my car class in that file and then be able to call it in the pygame window loop in the autopilot.py file. When I press a or d to go left or right my car sprite doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong? How can I code to move left or right in the car.py file and then call it in autopilot.py? Please help. An example will help too :)

autopilot.py code:

```
"""
BUGS LIST:
FIXED = No longer a bug in software
-------------------------------------------
FIXED(10-27-21: Having problems with the debris class (def draw_debris) function. The game outputs to the
screen but does not spawn in the cement block sprites from the top as I intended.)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FIXED(10-28-21: I can now spawn in a cement block at the top of the pygame window except I want to be
able to spawn in multiple of the same cement block along the top at different locations
not just have the same cement block sprite change its location randomly.)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10-28-21: Having trouble making car sprite move.

"""

import pygame
import debris
import car

pygame.init()

WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("AutoPilot")
screen.fill((255,255,255))

#fps
FPS = 120
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#background img
bg = pygame.image.load('background/street.png').convert_alpha()


#define variables


######################CAR/DEBRIS##########################

car = car.Car(475,200,5)
debris = debris.Debris(1,5)

##########################################################

#groups
car_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
car_group.add(car)

debris_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
debris_group.add(debris)


#simulation runs here
run = True
while run:

    #draw street
    screen.blit(bg,[0,0])

    #update groups
    car_group.update()
    debris_group.update()
    #debris_group.draw(screen)
    #car_group.draw(screen)

    #draw debris
    debris.draw()
    #debris.update()
    debris.fall()

    #draw car
    car.draw()

    #if y coordinate is > 0
    if debris.y > 0:
        debris.collide()


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        #check if key is down
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                car.movingLeft = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                car.movingRight = True
        #check if key is up
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                car.movingLeft = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                car.movingRight = False




    #update the display
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

pygame.quit()

car.py code:

```
import pygame

#screen height & width
WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))

#car class
class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, scale, speed):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.speed = speed
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.moving = True
        self.frame = 0
        self.flip = False
        self.direction = 0

        #load car
        self.images = []
        img = pygame.image.load('car/car.png').convert_alpha()
        img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (int(img.get_width()) * scale, (int(img.get_height()) * scale)))
        self.images.append(img)
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.update_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    #draw car to screen
    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.image,(self.x, self.y))

    #move car
    def move(self, movingLeft, movingRight):
        # reset the movement variables
        dx = 0
        dy = 0

        # moving variables
        if movingLeft:
            dx = -self.speed
            self.flip = True
            self.direction = -1
        if movingRight:
            dx = self.speed
            self.flip = False
            self.direction = 1

        # update rectangle position
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `self.x += dx` and `self.y += dy` in `Car.move`?

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Also, I don't think this is causing your current problem, but it's not a good idea to have a variable named `car` and also a `module` named `car`. The line `car = car.Car(475,200,5)` overwrites the module with the `Car` object, making the module inaccessible unless you re-import it later, which is bad practice.

Comment: My bad its bad habit I picked up is player = car.Car better? also I changed it to self.x += dx and self.y += dy and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There were multiple errors that needed fixing in order to make the car move:

1. `car.move` was never called
2. `car.move` took `movingLeft` and `movingRight` as arguments, but elsewhere they are assigned to as attributes of `car`
3. The line `screen.blit(self.image,(self.x, self.y))` draws the car at `(self.x, self.y)`, but the `move` method only changes `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y`.

Here is a version that has a moving car. Images are replaced with colored rectangles since I don't have access to your images, and the `debris` is removed since you didn't give that file. It's probably easier to modify your code with the changes above than modify this code to do what you want, but it's here for reference:

```
"""
BUGS LIST:
FIXED = No longer a bug in software
-------------------------------------------
FIXED(10-27-21: Having problems with the debris class (def draw_debris) function. The game outputs to the
screen but does not spawn in the cement block sprites from the top as I intended.)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FIXED(10-28-21: I can now spawn in a cement block at the top of the pygame window except I want to be
able to spawn in multiple of the same cement block along the top at different locations
not just have the same cement block sprite change its location randomly.)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10-28-21: Having trouble making car sprite move.

"""

import pygame
import numpy as np

#screen height & width
WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))

#car class
class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, scale, speed):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.speed = speed
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.moving = True
        self.frame = 0
        self.flip = False
        self.direction = 0

        #load car
        self.images = []
        img = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(np.full((20,30),180))
        img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (int(img.get_width()) * scale, (int(img.get_height()) * scale)))
        self.images.append(img)
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.update_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.movingLeft = False
        self.movingRight = False

    #draw car to screen
    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.image,(self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

    #move car
    def move(self):
        # reset the movement variables
        dx = 0
        dy = 0

        # moving variables
        if self.movingLeft:
            dx = -self.speed
            self.flip = True
            self.direction = -1
        if self.movingRight:
            dx = self.speed
            self.flip = False
            self.direction = 1

        # update rectangle position
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy


pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("AutoPilot")
screen.fill((255,255,255))

#fps
FPS = 120
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#background img
bg = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(np.full((WIDTH,HEIGHT),255))


#define variables


######################CAR/DEBRIS##########################

car = Car(475,200,5,1)

##########################################################

#groups
car_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
car_group.add(car)

debris_group = pygame.sprite.Group()


#simulation runs here
run = True
while run:

    #draw street
    screen.blit(bg,[0,0])

    #update groups
    car_group.update()
    debris_group.update()
    #debris_group.draw(screen)
    #car_group.draw(screen)

    #draw car
    car.draw()
    car.move()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        #check if key is down
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                car.movingLeft = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                car.movingRight = True
        #check if key is up
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                car.movingLeft = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                car.movingRight = False




    #update the display
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

This is not the easiest way of writing this, but I was trying to make minimal changes to your code.

Comment: Thanks Oli. It seems to work but now I am getting an error of "AttributeError: partially initialized module 'car' has no attribute 'Car' (most likely due to a circular import). How can I fix this?

Comment: @J.R.BEATS please post a separate question for this - I don't think I can work out exactly how to help you without more details.